# Why is lower 95% Confidence Interval below 1 when p value is significant

Tags: r, confidence-interval

I have two groups "Treated" and "Control" and by a test either positive or negative.  The p value by fishers.test is 0.04.  The Odds Ratio is 3.13 and the confidence intervals are 0.93-13.43.  I was under the impression that when the test is statistically significant then the confidence interval does not cross 1.00.

```
cat("Test \n")
matrix_with <-
matrix(c(12, (335-12), 4, (341-4)),
     nrow = 2,
     dimnames = list(Treated = c("Positive", "Negative"),
                     Control = c("Positive", "Negative")))
print(matrix_with)
cat("Proportions postive: TX followed by control\n")
print(12/335)
print(4/341)
print(fisher.test(matrix_with, alternative = "two.sided"))
#------------
    Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  matrix_with
p-value = 0.04477
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
  0.9348216 13.4298907
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
  3.125192
```

Results in Matlab command [h p stats] = fishertest([12, 4, 323, 337]).  Produces p=0.0448 and 95% CIs of [0.9992 9.8048].

And using the formula 
      SE_Log_OR = sqrt(1/12 + 1/4 + 1/323 + 1/337)
      Neg_95_CI = exp(log(3.13) - 1.96*SE_log_OR)
produced
Neg_95_CI of 0.9992

Comment: Looking at the code I think it's probably due to choices in the setup of the call to `uniroot` that are giving "different results" in a small numbers (the 4 and 12) situation. I think this is a numerical precision issue more than a statistic problem. Would you be making any real-world decision differently if the CI has a lower bound of `1.00348216`?

Comment: @42- I would be making a real world decision if the 95% CI was a 1.07 instead of a 0.93.  I am confused by the different results produced in the following packages: Results in R as above.  Results in Matlab command [h p stats] = fishertest(x).  Produces p=0.0448 and 95% CIs of [0.9992 9.8048].

Comment: And by using the formula

Comment: Apparently you have a quasi-religious view of making decisions. The strength of statistical evidence for a "difference" is pretty weak when the numbers are so small. Personally I think the difference is rather "arbitrary". I would have thought to move the goalposts so the  p-value threshold was 0.15 or 0.20

Comment: This is an answer from Ted Harding to very similar question in  2007 on Rhelp: http://markmail.org/message/ydxgukvl65pjnbwa?q=list:org%2Er-project%2Er-help+p-value+fisher%2Etest+lumley